# MongoDB get count of total records after applying query filters

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb, codeigniter-2

I just need to find the count of total records which i get from the mentioned query.

```
$orderData = $this->mongo_db->get_where('order', array('order_date'=> array('$gte'=>floatval(1337797800000), '$lte'=>floatval(1337970600000))));
```

I am using alexbilbie's library for codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

`echo count($orderData);` will return the number of records from your result

Comment: I am not using mysql library.